# Apply rejected edit to my answer

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Here is an [edit to my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9688796).

It was rejected by 3 of 4 reviewers, but IMO it's good edit and I want to apply it.
Is it possible to apply this edit, but to edit answer by myself in order to save author of this edit?

Comment: If you think using the edit feature to tell you about those changes is ok, we've got a bigger problem. It might just be the way you're wording this question that make me think you're ok with code changes in edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. Once rejected it can't be approved any more. You have to manually edit your question with the suggested edit.

There was a feature request to make this possible on Meta Stack Exchange (the uber Meta). You can find it here: [Allow the original poster the option to apply a rejected suggested edit on their own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252913/245360).